# SMTP servidor de correo no envía

Tags: php, html

**¿Por qué no se me envía el formulario de contacto al email?**
Tengo los archivos cargados en una página web y con un servidor **Filezilla**.

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\enviar.php on line 17
El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente.
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slider Jquery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <ul class="slider">
            <li>
                <a href="primera.html">
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                    <section class="caption">
                        <h1>Primera imagen</h1>
                        <p>Primera imagen. Slider personalizado.</p>
                    </section>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="segunda.html">
                <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
                <section class="caption">
                    <h1>Segunda imagen</h1>
                    <p>Segunda imagen. Slider personalizado.</p>
                </section>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="tercera.html">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
                <section class="caption">
                    <h1>Tercera imagen.</h1>
                    <p>Tercera imagen. Slider personalizado.</p>
                </section>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="cuarta.html">
                <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="">
                <section class="caption">
                    <h1>Cuarta imagen</h1>
                    <p>Cuarta imagen. Slider personalizado.</p>
                </section>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ol class="pagination">
        </ol>

        <div class="left">
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="formulario">
        <center>
        <h1>Formulario de contacto</h1><br/>

        <form action="enviar.php" method="post">
            Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduzca un nombre..." required />  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Introduzca un email..." required /><br/><br/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            Asunto: <input type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Introduzca un asunto..." required /><br/><br/>
            <textarea type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Introduzca un mensaje..." required cols="40" rows="3"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar mensaje"/>
        </form></center>
    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

**enviar.php**

```
    <?php
    $myemail = "omaza1900@hotmail.com";
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Asunto: $asunto";
    $email_body = "Has recibido un mensaje. 
                 \n Nombre: $nombre
                 \n Correo: $email
                 \n Mensaje: $mensaje
                 \n\n Muchas gracias por su atención.";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    echo "El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente."; 
    sleep(3);
    header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Comment: Los parámetros por separado funcionan (`$to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers`)? O el problema está en el envío únicamente? PD: El `$subject` no existe, tienes `name="nombre"` duplicado.

Comment: Aun así me sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Los parámetros por separado funcionan `($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers)`? Te los está reconociendo? Prueba a sacarlos por pantalla para ver si funciona y descartar que sea ese el problema, y no de conexión o servidor.

Comment: Conectando el XAMPP para probar desde el propio PC, he encontrado el siguiente error: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\enviar.php on line 17
El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente.

Comment: Así de primeras, te diría que no hay un servidor de correos local, o si lo hay, no está corriendo en el puerto 25. Compruébalo.

Comment: No tengo un servidor de correos local. Estoy cargando los archivos en Filezilla directamente con el servidor, usuario/contraseña y puerto 21, pero no tengo servidor SMTP para correo.

Comment: Sin servidor de correo no puedes enviar correos... Puedes configurar el de Gmail mismo.

Comment: Desde GMAIL, solo me salen las opciones de POP e IMAP, no me aparece para configurar SMTP.

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/108521/edit) colocando cómo aparece la configuración de los puertos de email en `php.ini`, creo que ayudaría a una respuesta más precisa sobre el problema. Quizá no exista tal configuración, esté comentada, y por tanto no esté funcionando, esté apuntando a otro puerto, etc. Me refiero a esta parte del `php.ini`:  `[mail function] ...`

Comment: [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas un servidor de correos SMTP y configurarlo, pregunta si donde hosteas la pagina tienen servidor de correo o usa alguno gratis como el de gmail

en tu ejempo estas usando una cuenta de hotmail, necesitas una de gmail

tienes que setear estos parametros.

Server: smtp.gmail.com
Encryption/Authentication: SSL
Port: 465

O

Server: smtp.gmail.com
Encryption/Authentication: StartTLS
Port: 587

ejemplo

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//indico a la clase que use SMTP
$mail­>IsSMTP();
//permite modo debug para ver mensajes de las cosas que van ocurriendo
$mail­>SMTPDebug = 2;
//Debo de hacer autenticación SMTP
$mail­>SMTPAuth = true;
$mail­>SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
$mail­>Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//indico el puerto que usa Gmail
$mail­>Port = 465;
//indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
$mail­>Username = "tu_correo_electronico_gmail@gmail.com";
$mail­>Password = "tu clave";
$mail­>SetFrom('tu_correo_electronico_gmail@gmail.com', 'Nombre completo');
$mail­>AddReplyTo("tu_correo_electronico_gmail@gmail.com","Nombre completo");
$mail­>Subject = "Envío de email usando SMTP de Gmail";
$mail­>MsgHTML("Hola que tal, esto es el cuerpo del mensaje!");
//indico destinatario
$address = "destinatario@delcorreoe.com";
$mail­>AddAddress($address, "Nombre completo");
if(!$mail­>Send()) {
echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail­>ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Mensaje enviado!";
}
```

[Envio de mail en php usando smtp de gmail](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/envio-mail-usando-smtp-gmail.html)

Comment: Tengo lo siguiente en mi php.ini

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25